# Check the conditions in comma separated values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter. In my table one of the field contain value like 1,2 or 1 or 2. Now I want to check a condition in model. The column name is period that value is mentioned above.

**model**

```
  if($post_period == 1)
        {
            $this->db->where('period',1);             
        }
        else if($post_period == 2)  
            {
                $this->db->where('period',2);      
            }
```

Comment: $post_period =  1,2 or 1 or 2?

Comment: these three are possible

Comment: than i think you may use if($post_period ==1 || $post_period==2){}else if($post_period ==1){} else if($post_period == 2){}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Mysql Function FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist) .

Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings.

A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by `“,”` characters.
If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET, the `FIND_IN_SET()` function is optimized to use bit arithmetic.

Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL.

**This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.**

```
 $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET( '$post_period' , period) ");
```

Comment: SELECT `id`, IF (`period` = 4 , 'p_fee','(SUM(`p_fee2`+`p_fee1`))' as totfee ) FROM tbl